Movie about people invited to an island where one is a killer
I am looking for the title for a movie where a group of people (that may have been friends) have been invited to an island. Soon they are killed one at a time. They've suspect that the killer is one of group. The killer wears a mask. The end of the film (as far as i remember) leaves 2 survivors, a man and a woman. They escape the island on a boat. They believe that they have killed the killer, but to their surprise the killer is also in the boat. They fight until the killer is drowned. They tied him in the woods and cut his body in two.

Approximate year? Country\language? Possible actors?

Sounds a bit like Club Dread. Though technically a comedy, it does have an island with a masked killer.  The killer even gets cut in half in the end when attacking the survivors in a boat.

The wiki plot summary sounds very close to the description of the OP.

I think it's Mindhunters with Val Kilmer. It's about a group of FBI trainees on an island with a mysterious killer in their midst.
Full movie here.

Sounds to me like A Perfect Getaway (2009):

Two pairs of lovers on a Hawaiian vacation discover that psychopaths
  are stalking and murdering tourists on the islands.





It's And Then There Were None from a novel by Agatha Christie.  There have been various adaptions for screen and TV.  The first I could find was 1945.  It also goes under the name Ten Little Indians.

Except if the scenario had been changed for the movie, the ending does not match with Ten Little Indians.

In Ten Little Indians the location changed to a mountain château.  But there have been many adaptions including a 2015 version.  I am sure the 1945 And Then There Were None is exactly as described.

I recently saw An Then There Were None and the killer is killed on the island.

Sounds like Harper’s Island (2008):

Harper’s Island is an American murder mystery television series. [T]he narrative followed the guests of a wedding party who were killed
  one at a time.


You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the descriptions from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.

Wasn't Harper's Island a tv show?
